# Redux Reducer: key injection into state

Tags: dynamic, key, redux

First, I do understand this is a mutated state change; I know shame on me. Sometimes the correct way doesn't appear to be the smartest or I at least don't know any better.

Let me explain, I wan't to inject keys into my state without creating and exchanging old state and new state for predefined items. I simply want to inject keys for a while and if I don't then they are all cleared anyway. My initial state looks like

```
{graphSite: {site: "default", graphBrowser: { graphID: '', graphKey:'' }, browsable:[] }};
```

my reducer looks like this **using babel es7 object spread operator

```
case BROWSER: { state.graphSite.browsable[action.id] = action.payload
                return {...state}
               }
```

So this will work but redux dev tools doesnt show the state change though the browsable array is accessible perhaps this is because I went against the grain though if I extend the changes to:

```
case BROWSER:  { state.graphSite.browsable[action.id] = action.payload
                        return {...state, 
                                graphSite: {...state.graphSite, 
                                    graphBrowser: {...state.graphSite.graphBrowser},
                                    browsable: {...state.graphSite.browsable}   }
                                }
                            }
```

now browsable shows correctly in the tool, but ideally I these are the same thing.

So the question is what is the best way to manipulate the state for dynamic keys that are not in the initial store state. This works just feels like I'm doing something wrong because I manipulated the original state.

Comment: you are mutating the state itself. `state.graphSite.browsable[action.id] = action.payload`. You need to do a deep copy of state, and mutate the copy they way you do, then return the copy

Comment: I wanted the action ids to be dynamic enough i dont have to keep track of the possible initial states to change.  The problem is there is nothing to copy unless you mutate the original and return it as the new.  Otherwise id do the normal object spread and the piece i want changed. This was mainly all for the sake of key because if this was an array i cant guarantee the order from async calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title confused me in the first place. `dynamic key injection` sounds way too fancy for me :P.

Anyway, you actually want to add a new pair to your `browserble`.
You had:

```
case BROWSER: { state.graphSite.browsable[action.id] = action.payload
            return {...state}
           }
```

This is wrong (assuming `state` comes form reducer parameter), because you are directly modifying the `state` object.

One of the principle of redux is that `Changes are made with pure functions`. (redux docs).

FTFY:

```
case BROWSER: { 
  const nextState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)); // deep copy your state
  nextState.graphSite.browsable[action.id] = action.payload
  return nextState
}
```

This isn't most effecient code, `JSON`operations are expensive. It is just to demonstrate the principle of not mutating the state object directly.

Answer (score -2):

Alright, I couldn't see in the context of the object spread how to append variable keys and without created initial store states. This is pretty straightforward after copying the state then returning the appended like so; both worked this one is just now not modifying the original state.

```
case BROWSER:  { let browser = {...state} 
                         browser.graphSite.browsable[action.id] = action.payload
                        return {...state, 
                                graphSite: {...state.graphSite, 
                                    graphBrowser: {...state.graphSite.graphBrowser},
                                    browsable: {...browser.graphSite.browsable}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Destructuring works great here

```
case BROWSER:  { let {graphSite: {browsable: browser}} = state
                         browser[action.id] = action.payload
    
                        return {...state, 
                                graphSite: {...state.graphSite, 
                                    graphBrowser: {...state.graphSite.graphBrowser},
                                    browsable: {...browser}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

I also realize I could use something like deepFreeze or immutable to check for these but practicing.

Comment: **note**: object spread operator shallow copies your state. therefore, you code is still modifying the state directly which can cause unexpected bugs.